# How to remove 'google' is undefined error from IE 11 (Angular 8)?

Tags: angular, google-maps, internet-explorer

I am integrating Google Maps APIs in an Angular 8 application.
However, I am getting the following error: `'Google' is undefined` in the `vendor.js` file.

> SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined vendor.js (125681,3)

Comment: is it working in chrome?

Comment: Try [enabling TLS](https://www.bauer-power.net/2014/06/how-to-enabled-tls-11-and-tls-12-in.html).

Comment: You should ask why this message is showing up and solve the problem. I don't think just removing solves the problem you have.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the Google API reference load success? Besides, please check the Google API key, make sure it's not expired.